# How to calculate the mean distance between co-ordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, coordinates, measurements

I have an assignment were I need to calculate the mean distance between coordinates. Effectively I am trying to find out what is the average distance in meters between buildings in a defined town boundary.

Does QGIS have a tool to do this? I'm using WGS 84 as the co-ordinates system for the both the project and the layer.

[image: Building Co-ordinates in a town]

Comment: Is it mean distance between all coordinates (i.e. you calculate distances from building 1 to all other buildings, repeat on building 2, 3, etc, and get global average), or do you want the mean distance between closely spaced buildings, or something else entirely? You might want to define your question more clearly :)

Comment: Hi Weiji, yes I want to find the distance in meters between closely spaced buildings i.e. the nearest neighbouring building.

Answer (score 5):

To find statistics on the nearest neighbors, you would go to `Vector > Analysis tools > Nearest Neighbor Analysis`. Upon completion, it displays a window that includes the mean distance. Make sure you are using a projected dataset to obtain distances in meters, not in degrees.

Comment: Thanks JGH, I saved the project layer and the points layer as Irish Grid 95 and it worked! The results were in meters.